# Cumulative volume till now since previous 15 min bar close in 1 minute chart

Tags: pine-script

I want to find our the cumulative volume since last 15 minute bar close, on 1 minute chart. I think there might be two options:

Base chart is on 1 minute.

Option 1:
Call security function to get the 15 min volume:

````
volume15min = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "15", volume)```
````

Does above will get updated, as chart move forward on 1 min chart. For example, volume15min[1] give the volume of closed bar, and volume15min can gives real time volume updated every minute. Looks like volume15min does not change in real time on 1 minute chart.

Option 2:
Round the current time to last 15 minute (how to get current time?), find the gap between rounded 15 min and current minute, and sum volume over that many minute bars.

How can I make anyone of the option to get the data I need?

Answer (score 0):

`ta.change(time("15"))` function will return true every 15 minutes. You can use this to check the length between current bar and the beginning of the 15 minute session with `ta.barssince()` function, and than use this number as the argument in the `math.sum()` function:

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script")

new_session = ta.change(time("15"))
bars_since_new_session = ta.barssince(new_session)
total_volume = bars_since_new_session >= 0 ? math.sum(volume, bars_since_new_session + 1) : volume

plot(total_volume)
```